# How to optionally capture a Regex value?

Tags: regex

I know the question has been asked before.
But I cannot seem to find a solution to this:

Here is the test strings

```
value: value1, Do not include this
value: value2
```

Here is my regex: `value: (.*)(?:, Do not include this)?`

The result should capture

```
value1
value2
```

But instead it captures this

```
value1, Do not include this
value2
```

**[EDIT]**
Based on the comments and answers.
Let me clarify.

if this is the test string

```
value: value1, Do not include this
value: value1, test,
value: man, this is bad!!, Do not include this
```

Then the captured values should be this:

```
value1
value1, test, test,
man, this is bad!!
```

Comment: `value: ([^,]+)` https://regex101.com/r/5wk5eB/1

Comment: this will break if the test string = `value: man, this is bad!!, Do not include this`

Comment: Then you have to add the optional group after it `value: ([^,]+)(?:, Do not include this)?` https://regex101.com/r/Ua8AnB/1 Or if that is the only thing allowed after it `value: ([^,]+)(?:, Do not include this|$)`  https://regex101.com/r/0qcBwE/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```regex
value: (.*)(?:, Do not include this)?
       ---- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        A              B
```

The problem with your expression, is, that part A is allowed to match the whole line and part B is optional. The regex engine, upon encountering A, will simply jump to the end of the line it is currently matching against and consume all characters on the way. Then, having matched A, it will advance to part B of the expression, see that it can't be matched (because the whole line was already consumed) and that it is optional, and, this being the end of the expression, stop this attempt and declare the match successful.

One way to prevent this from happening, would be to make part A lazy while forcing the expression to match the whole line by using an end-of-line anchor. For example:

```regex
value: (.*?)(?:, Do not include this)?$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/XS9tM7/1).

You could also make part A and B so distinct from each other, that you don't have to worry about one matching in place of the other. If applicable, this would allow you to keep the greedy quantifier for part A. For example:

```regex
value: ([^,]*)(?:, Do not include this)?
```

Which way is more suitable to your needs depends on the composition of the strings you match against.

Comment: I have updated the question. It looks like your answer, (as well as the guy who commented) stops at the first comment.

Comment: @FlowUI.SimpleUITesting.com I added a link to a demo.

Comment: Glad it worked. The more important part, I think, was the explanation why your expression did not work the way you wanted it to. I hope that part was understandable; I'm not good at the writing thing. ^^